# Bulk Inserting data to table which have default current timestamp column

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table on redshift with following structure

```
CREATE TABLE schemaName.tableName (
some_id INTEGER,
current_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT GETDATE()
);
```

If I bulk insert data from other table for example

```
INSERT INTO schemaName.tableName (some_id) SELECT id FROM otherSchema.otherTable;
```

Will the value for `current_time` column be same for all bulk inserted rows? Or it will depend on insertion time for each record. As the column data-type is `TIMESTAMP`

I am considering this for Amazon Redshift only.

So far I have tested with changing the default value of `current_time` column to  `SYSDATE` and bulk inserting 10 rows to target table. `current_time` column values per row yields results like `2016-11-16 06:38:52.339208` and are same for each row, where `GETDATE()` yields result like `2016-11-16 06:43:56`. I haven't found any documentation regarding this and need confirmation regarding this.

To be precise, all rows get same timestamp values after executing following statement

```
INSERT INTO schemaName.tableName (some_id) SELECT id FROM otherSchema.otherTable;
```

But if I change the table structure to following

```
  CREATE TABLE schemaName.tableName (
  some_id INTEGER,
  current_time DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT RANDOM()
  );
```

rows get different random values for `current_time`

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Redshift will have same default value in the case of bulk insert. The [RedshiftDocumentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_loading_default_values.html) has the below content:

> the evaluated DEFAULT expression for a given column is the same for
>   all loaded rows, a DEFAULT expression that uses a RANDOM() function
>   will assign to same value to all the rows.

Comment: This is for `COPY` command. Just tested with `RANDOM() ` function with bulk insert and doesn't yield same result for all rows.